# Parallelize the other loop of a nested for loop using allgather

Tags: mpi, distributed-computing, hpc, openmpi, mpich

I am trying to parallelize a nested for loop below using allgather

```
for (int i=0; i<N1; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<N0; j++)
            HS_1[i] += IN[j]*W0[j][i];
    }
```

Here N1 is 1000 and N2 is 764.

I have four processes and I just want to parallelize the outer loop. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a matrix-vector multiplication. Let's assume that you've distributed the `HS` output vector. Each component needs the full `IN` vector, so you indeed need an allgather for that. You also need to distribute the `W0` matrix: each process gets part of the `i` indices, and all of the `j` indices.

Comment: IN and W0 is available to all other process, In that case, will the following code work?

Comment: `partition = N1/num_proc;</br>
 start = rank * partition;  
 end = start + partition;  

 double hs_1[partition];
 for (int i = start; i < end; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < N0; j++)
   hs_1[i-start] += N[j] * W0[j][i];
 }

 MPI_Allgatherv(hs_1, N1/rank, MPI_DOUBLE, HS_1, N1/rank, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);      `

Comment: That code looks correct, but it's pointless. You have your matrix on each process, but they only use a small part of it. And why do you gather the result at all? A good MPI application works completely distributed.